# MongoDB query performance issues lock data use function

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm experiencing performance issues as follows:

```
Table :  { _id, procedure, latitude, longitude}
```

I want to write one api retrieve the gap is largest 5Km:

```
Api: SearchProductByLocalAroundHere(double latitude, double longitude, int lmax)
```

I created one function in order to calculate the distance mongdb:

```
CalculateDistance

function (latitude0, longitude0, latitude1, longitude1, lmax) {
var pi = 3.1415926535897931;     var circumference = 40000.0;     var distance = 0.0;     var latitude0Rad = latitude0 * pi / 180.0;     var longitude0Rad = longitude0 * pi / 180.0;     var latititude1Rad = latitude1 * pi / 180.0;     var longitude1Rad = longitude1 * pi / 180.0;     var logitudeDiff = Math.abs(longitude0Rad - longitude1Rad);     if (logitudeDiff > pi)       logitudeDiff = 2.0 * pi - logitudeDiff;     var angleCalculation = Math.acos( Math.sin(latititude1Rad) * Math.sin(latitude0Rad) + Math.cos(latititude1Rad) * Math.cos(latitude0Rad) * Math.cos(logitudeDiff));     distance = circumference * angleCalculation / (2.0 * pi);     return distance <=lmax; }
```

And I use it (C#)

```
 var query = Query.EQ("$where", string.Format("CalculateDistance(this.latitude,this.longitude,{0},{1},{2})", latitude, longitude, lmax));

            var result = _collection.Find(query).SetLimit(2000).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToList();
```

I have a problem when the number of database lock> 200000.

Looking forward to your help and direction for me.

Thank!

Comment: Please fix your code formatting (it was even worse before the edit). Also, why aren't you using MongoDB's built-in geo functionality? What makes your use case so special? If you really have to use `$where`, expect catastrophic performance.

Comment: Hi,You may say more is not? You should give her an example and plan on how to deal with that. Thank